# Given $ f: [a, b] \to \mathbb R $ and $ n \in \mathbb N $, assume $ h = \frac {b-a}{}\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

> Given $ f: [a, b] \to \mathbb R $ and $ n \in \mathbb N $, assume $ h = \frac {b-a} {n} $ and the average of the numbers $ f ( a + h ), \ldots, f (a + nh) = f (b) $ given by
> $$ M (f; n) = \frac {1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f (a + kh) $$
> Show that if $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$, then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} M (f; n) = \frac{1} {b-a} \int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$

> For this reason, the number $ \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x) \, dx $ is called the average of $ f $ in $[a,b]$.

Proof

We take the partition $P$ with $t_0 = a$, $t_1 = a + \frac{b-a}{n}$, … ,$t_k = a + \frac{{k(b-a)}}{n}$, … , $t_n = b$ with $\Delta  t_{k-1} = \frac{b-a}{n}$, we dither the partition taking in each $[t_{k-1},t_k]$ the point $t_k$ we have with that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^nf(a+kh)= \int_a^bf(x) \, dx$$ and so on $$\lim_{n \to \infty} M(f,n) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x) \, dx$$

---

I found this proof and I don't think I understood it very well.

I know from class that $S(f; P)= \sum_{k=1}^n f(\alpha_k)(t_k-t_{k-1})$

where $P={}$dotted partition (sorry I don't know the English term)
and
$(t_k-t_{k-1})= \Delta t_k$ and in this case $(t_k-t_{k-1})= \Delta t_k = \frac{b-a}{n}$

then it would look like this $S(f, P)= \sum_{k=1}^n f(a+kh)\Delta t_k$? then the delta was removed from the sum and the limit was added to get the integral and we were like this $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^nf(a+kh)= \int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$

and we can do this because $f$ is integrable so it is also valid that $L= \lim_{\left|P\right| \to 0} S(f;P)$ but if it were that $n$ would tend to zero and not to infinity right?

And if that's what was done

To finish
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(a+kh)= (b-a)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(a+kh)=\int_a^bf(x) \, dx $$
we divide by $b-a$ and we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(a+kh)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^bf (x)\,dx=\lim_{n \to \infty} M(f,n)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$

So how much did I understand correctly?

Thank's in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you heard of Riemann sums ?

Comment: we are less intimate than i would like but i heard about,

Comment: what's the _definition_ of "integrable"???

Comment: It is Riemann integrable if there is a limit $L= \lim_{\left|P\right| \to 0} S(f;P)$

Comment: The limit $$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+kh)=\int_a^b f(t)dt $$ is exactly a Riemann sum. In fact I should write $h_n$ instead of $h$, the norm of the partition $(a+kh_n)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$ is $\frac{b-a}{n}=h$ so that the limit $|P|\rightarrow 0$ means that $h\rightarrow 0$, or $n\rightarrow +\infty$ in this case.